# Folder pop open but not in Finder

Tags: macos, folders

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.5 on my iMac. In the dock at the bottom of the screen, there is a collection of folders on the right side of the dock. When I click on one of these folders it pops open but not in Finder. It has a look as shown here. I added a folder to the dock but it doesn't respond like this. Is there a way to make folders in the dock respond this way? And what is this called?

When I right click on the new added folder I get the options shown at the bottom.

[image: here]      [image: pop2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new folder you added to the dock is is not a real folder but an alias to another folder. The little mark in the bottom corner is a small arrow indicating it’s pointing to something else, the thing it is aliased to. Put the real or original folder in the dock and it will work like the other folders in the dock, including the appearance options for list view.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your folder in Dock and choose "List" for "View content as".

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: I don't have that option on the newly added folder.